# How do you add the value for a certain column from a previous row to your current row in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want my for loop to dynamically update the value for "change in NWC"

`#add new column for the change in NWC`
`df["Change_in_NWC"] = 0`
`#value of new row = value for "wcap" this minus value "wcap" from previous row`
`for row in range(len(df)):`
`df.iloc[row]["Change_in_NWC"] = df.iloc[row]["wcap"]-df.iloc[row-1]["wcap"]`

`I needed the values to dynamically update which they did not.`

Comment: Please format your code so it's easier to read. Also have you tried something so far? What problems are you facing?

Comment: Try `df['wcap'].diff()`